# Uncaught ReferenceError onKeyPress

Tags: html, angular, typescript, onkeypress

I want to see if a user is typing a letter or a number. It works when I use a @HostListener but not when I use the onKeyPress in HTML.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="table">
 <div class="cell" *ngFor="let number of [_,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">
  <input class="number" value="{{number}}" disabled>
 </div>
 <div class="row" *ngFor="let row of grid?.boxArray; let i = index">
  <input class="number" value="{{i+1}}" disabled>
   <div class="cell" *ngFor="let col of grid?.boxArray; let j = index">
    <input type="text" onKeyPress="detectLetter('$event')" id="{{i}}_{{j}}" class="box" maxLength="1"
           [ngClass]="{ 'sel': grid.boxArray[i][j].isSelectedHint, 'unsel': !grid.boxArray[i][j].isSelectedHint, 'black': grid.boxArray[i][j].isBlack }" >
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is the function detectLetter()

```
public detectLetter(event: KeyboardEvent, x: number, y: number): void {
   const key: number = event.keyCode;
   if ( key < 65 || key > 122) {
     alert("It's not a letter");
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling your JS with Flow? Because if you are not, this is invalid syntax. Also, check your developer console to see if you can see any other errors.

Comment: Replace onKeyPress="detectLetter('$event') by onKeyPress="detectLetter($event). If you put $event into quotes it gets passed as a simple string.

Comment: @SumnerEvans No I use npm start to compile.

Comment: @DiabolicWords It doesn't work

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the console of your browser? (mostly you have to press F12 to activate the developer's console)

Comment: (keypress) instead of onKeyPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get this error that the angular has their own methods like (keypress), so you have to little change your code:

```
<div class="table">
 <div class="cell" *ngFor="let number of [_,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">
  <input class="number" value="{{number}}" disabled>
 </div>
 <div class="row" *ngFor="let row of grid?.boxArray; let i = index">
  <input class="number" value="{{i+1}}" disabled>
   <div class="cell" *ngFor="let col of grid?.boxArray; let j = index">
    <input type="text" (keypress)="detectLetter($event)" id="{{i}}_{{j}}" class="box" maxLength="1"
           [ngClass]="{ 'sel': grid.boxArray[i][j].isSelectedHint, 'unsel': !grid.boxArray[i][j].isSelectedHint, 'black': grid.boxArray[i][j].isBlack }" >
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I think the better way in your case is to use (keyup)